# Plot3D fails to display a discontinuous function

Tags: plotting

```
w = 100 π;
vra1[t_] := 0.8 Sin[w t];
vrb1[t_] := 0.8 Sin[w t - 2 π/3];
vrc1[t_] := 0.8 Sin[w t + 2 π/3];
ia[t_, θ_] := 7.2 Sin[w t - θ];
ib[t_, θ_] := 7.2 Sin[w t - θ - 2 π/3];
ic[t_, θ_] := 7.2 Sin[w t - θ + 2 π/3];
v0[t_, θ_] := 
  Sign[vra1[t]] ia[t, θ] + Sign[vrb1[t]] ib[t, θ] + Sign[vrc1[t]] ic[t, θ];
Plot3D[v0[t, θ], {t, 0, 0.02}, {θ, -π, π}]
```

`Plot3D` does not dispaly the surface `v0[t, θ]`; it only shows the three dimensional axes. Please help me.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5htbs.png)

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Would you please change your name for better identification?

Comment: @J.M. We suppose it's a version-related problem. It failed in version 9.0.1 as I tested.

Comment: Same here, but the function is ok because when I use the `ListPlot3D` I got the plot. Perhaps more `PlotPoints`
?

Comment: @mm.Jang, what happens if you directly feed the right-hand side of `v0[t, θ]` to `Plot3D[]`?

Comment: I changed the `Sign` with the function itself over the absolute value of the function and it works better.

Comment: @J.M. I get empty box on 9.0.1.

Comment: `Compile` `v0` and plot the compiled one.

Comment: Empty plot for me on 8.0.4

Answer (score 10):

As far as I can tell this is a problem with the exclusions detection, which is removing all the vertices from the mesh.

A workaround is to use `Exclusions -> None`:

```
Plot3D[v0[t, θ], {t, 0, 0.02}, {θ, -π, π}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The problem is connected to the scale of the two input axes/domains, namely `{t, 0, 0.02}` and `{θ, -π, π}`, which have a ratio of less than 1/300.  The discontinuities are at lines of the form `t == const`, which are, of course, perpendicular to the `t` axis.  It is **as if** the excluded region is depends on the distance `Sqrt[Δt^2 + Δθ^2]` in the absolute geometry and not the display geometry. If the ratio of the scales is far from 1, the exclusions are not computed very accurately.  Depending on whether the ratio is much less than 1 or much greater, the excluded portion of the plot is, inversely, greater or less resp.   There is more to it than that, since `MaxRecursion` affects the computation of exclusions in an odd way.  It is probably quite complicated.

#### Solution

A rescaling of the `t` axis by about `100` produces a nice plot at the expense of having the wrong tick marks.  The ticks can be fixed with the `Ticks` option, if desired, as shown below.

```
scale = 100;
tticks = First @ With[{plotrange = {{0, 0.02}, {-Pi, Pi}}},
    Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[
      Graphics[{Line[Transpose@plotrange]}, PlotRange -> plotrange, Axes -> True],
      Ticks]];
Plot3D[v0[t/scale, θ],
 {t, 0, 0.02 scale}, {θ, -π, π},
 Ticks -> {MapAt[scale # &, tticks, {All, 1}], Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Some analysis of the problem

Increasing the scale too much causes discontinuites to be missed.  Here only the central gap is found.

```
scale = 10^6;
Plot3D[v0[t/scale, θ], {t, 0, 0.02 scale}, {θ, -π, π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Scaling by `10` is too little.  We can see that the dependency on `MaxRecursion` has no consistent pattern.  `MaxRecursion` settings higher than 3 produce no plots.

```
scale = 10;
GraphicsRow @ Table[
  Plot3D[v0[t/scale, θ], {t, 0, 0.02 scale}, {θ, -π, π}, MaxRecursion -> rec],
  {rec, 0, 3}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Scaling `t` has a greater effect than increasing `PlotPoints`:

```
grid = Table[
   Plot3D[
    v0[t/scale, θ], {t, 0,  0.02 scale}, {θ, -π, π},
    PlotPoints -> pp, ViewPoint -> Front],
   {scale, {5, 10, 20}}, {pp, {15, 25, 50}}
   ];
Labeled[GraphicsGrid[grid, ImageSize -> 500], {"scale", "points"}, {Left, Bottom},
 RotateLabel -> True, LabelStyle -> "Label"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully, this is not as drastic as the proposal to compile the function. The trick is something well-known to those who know it:

```
v0[t_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ] :=
           Sign[Through[{vra1, vrb1, vrc1}[t]]].Through[{ia, ib, ic}[t, θ]]
```

where I have also taken the liberty to compact the definition slightly. The idea is to thwart the preliminary symbolic analysis `Plot3D[]` seems to try on your function, where it becomes rather overzealous in excluding what it thinks should be excluded. It should produce the same plots featured in Simon's and Spawn's answers...

Answer (score 3):

You have two options. Either you compile your function `v0`:

```
vv = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {θ, _Real}}, v0[t, θ]]
```

and plot it instead

```
Plot3D[vv[t,θ], {t, 0, 0.02}, {θ, -π, π}]
```

or define the two new functions `f` and `v1`

```
f[t_] := If[t > 0, If[π - Mod[Abs[t], 2 π] > 0 , 1, -1],
            If[t<0, If[π - Mod[Abs[t], 2 π] > 0 , -1, 1], 0]]
```

*or*

```
f[t_] = Sin[t]/Abs[Sin[t]]
```

and

```
v1[t_, θ_] := f[w t] ia[t, θ] + f[w t - 2 π/3] ib[t, θ] +f[w t + 2 π/3] ic[t, θ];
```

and plot `v1` instead

```
Plot3D[v1[t, θ], {t, 0, 0.02}, {θ, -π, π}]
```

> [image]