# Plot3D with Piecewise is Empty

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I don't understand what has happened here. Please can someone explain? I start by defining a 2D function and plotting a couple of cases

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, t_] :=  E^(-10 (x - 1)^2)
              Piecewise[{{Sin[t/0.001 π], 0 <= t <= 0.001}, 
                         {0, 0.001 < t}}]
Plot[f[x, 0.0004], {x, 0, 2}]
Plot[f[0.9, t], {t, 0, 0.0015}]
```

This gives what I expect

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I then do

```
a = Table[f[x, t], {x, 0, 2, 0.1}, {t, 0, 0.0015, 0.0001}];
ListPlot3D[a, PlotRange -> All]
```

and this gives what I expect

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when I do

```
Plot3D[f[x, t], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 0.0015}, PlotRange -> All]
```

all I get is an empty box

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Investigating I do

```
b = Reap[Plot3D[Sow[f[x, t]], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 0.0015}, 
    PlotRange -> All]];
```

b[[1]] gives the same empty box and

```
b[[2, 1, 1 ;; 5]]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where the second value is the function. I have checked all the values beyond the first 5 and they are all numbers.

Why can't I Plot3D? Version 10.2

Thanks

Comment: I left off the zero in your definition of `f`. The documentation indicates that the default is zero for undefined regions. I thought you might be running into trouble if the plotting algorithm used a slightly negative value for `t`. Unfortunately, this didn't help at all. Duplicated your results.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Use `f[x_?NumberQ, t_?NumberQ]` when defining `f` and it plots fine.

Comment: @bills Thanks a simple solution. Any idea why? I note that the Reap now has an f[x,t] so it tries and fails but this time is not upset.

Comment: Apparently the exclusions are swallowing up the whole plot. Add `Exclusions -> None` and it works fine.

Comment: I wish there was a way to control the width of the exclusions: compare `Plot3D[f[x, t/1000], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All]` and `Plot3D[f[x, t/100], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 0.15}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: @Rahul I think you have nailed it. I still don't understand why the second point (retrieved from `Reap` and `Sow`) is symbolic.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your comments. Please could you write this up as an answer? I don't know why Exclusions should be the problem. Help states that `...excludes all subregions where discontinuities are found in functions being plotted. The discontinuities can involve either finite or infinite jumps in function values` . There are jumps in my function but the exclusions go beyond this. Also, why should insisting that values are Numeric (bill s) also work? Is this a bug?

Comment: @Rahul Shouldn't *M* have better automatic control of the width? I feel this should be considered a bug. (One can still wish for user-controlled widths, too.) -- Hugh, the `?NumericQ` works by preventing the discontinuity analysis that produces the `Exclusions`.

Comment: Interesting: `Plot3D[f[x, t], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 0.0015}, PlotRange -> All, ExclusionsStyle -> Red]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Very interesting. Also why do the Plot3D variants from Rahul work? Adding your ExclusionsStyle to those shows some scale dependence on Exclusion.

Comment: @Hugh What Rahul is saying is that the there is a fixed (minimum) width of the excluded domain (about the "discontinuity" in `Piecewise`) where the plot is interrupted.  Either turn off exclusions-processing or rescale the plot so that the plot is wider than the width of the excluded part of the domain.  (N.B. The "discontinuity" is an algebraic one, a change in formula, not an analytic discontinuity as defined in calculus/analysis.)  Note also that `ExclusionsStyle` is used to style the "excluded part" of the plot.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes that makes sense. It is interesting that it is a fixed width and not a width that is a fraction of the plot range.  I guess this is difficult to organise. Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23687/plot3d-fails-to-display-a-function-ive-defined/56691#56691 -- Does it seem a duplicate to anyone?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Happy to make it a duplicate. Would it help if I changed the main title to make it easy to find. How about Plot3D with Piecewise or Discontinuities?

Comment: @Hugh I changed the title of the other question.  You're right, it needed improvement, though it's probably better if it's not exactly the same as this.  I can mark this question a duplicate, if that's ok.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes mark mine as a duplicate. However, if you are stuck with this problem what would you look up to help? We ought to find a title that is general. Any ideas?

Comment: Both questions will remain on site. They'll be linked. Perhaps `Plot3D with Piecewise is empty" might be a better title for yours.  Having both with different titles makes it twice as likely that the next person will find one of them.  The main problem with searching on the site is that the user searches for what they think is the problem, but since they might not know what the problem is, they have to be lucky to find a solution. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[I intend to close this question as a duplicate shortly, as nearly a full day has passed since [Rahul](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul) pointed out the main problem; but since I had put together the following code before I found the duplicate, I wanted to share it with the OP. Not wanting to profit unfairly, I've marked this a community-wiki post.]*

Rahul pointed out that the problem is with `Exclusions`:

> Apparently the exclusions are swallowing up the whole plot. Add `Exclusions -> None` and it works fine. – Rahul

The following shows that the interval around a discontinuity is roughly fixed.  As we scale the plot, the gap appear to get narrower due to the scaling, but the numerical difference in the values of `t` is rougly constant.

```
GraphicsGrid@Partition[
 plots = Table[
    With[{sc = 2^i},
     Plot3D[{f[x, t/sc]}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, sc 0.0015}, 
      PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {-2.4, 1.3, 2.}]
     ],
    {i, 4, 7}],
  2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we extract the values of `t` from the plots and find the largest gap, we see they are all about `0.0115`.

```
tvals = Sort@
     DeleteDuplicates@
      Cases[#[[1, 1]], {x_Real, t_Real, z_Real} :> t, Infinity] & /@ 
   plots;

(Max@*Differences /@ tvals)
(*  {0.0115164, 0.0116862, 0.0114517, 0.0117392}  *)
```

The same problem occurs with `ParametricPlot3D`, but it is more convenient to scale the graph so that the coordinates remain the same.  (The gap around the discontinuity is placed around the **input**, not around the output.)

```
With[{sc = 10^3},
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {x, t/sc, f[x, t/sc]},
  {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, sc 0.0015},
  PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}, ViewPoint -> {-2.4, 1.3, 2.}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another note: The "discontinuity" in the OP's case is simply detected from `Piecewise`. In fact, the formulas define a continuous function.  So in that case, Rahul's solution of setting `Exclusions -> None` is the most appropriate, as well as the easiest, solution.

```
Plot3D[f[x, t], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 0.0015},
 PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, ViewPoint -> {-2.4, 1.3, 2.}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]